# apt-get doesn't delete\create directory in /etc

Tags: debian, apt

I don't understand if it's a bug or I don't know something.

I installed, for example `mysql-server` package with:

apt-get install mysql-server

It installs and works well. Then I try to delete it and it's configs:

apt-get purge mysql-server

As I understand from the manuals, purge delete all package's configs,
but directory `/etc/mysql` is still there. I then deleted it
manually:

```
rm -r /etc/mysql
```

But when I tried to install the package again, it doesn't create dir in `/etc`
and of course the package doesn't work. It happens not only with MySQL, but with
numerous other packages, including Apache vim.

What should I do?

This is on Debian 7 "wheezy".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure that you are purging the package which actually contains the config files.  For example, /etc/mysql/my.cnf is not owned by the mysql-server package, but is owned by the mysql-common package.  You can see this by running `dpkg -S /etc/mysql` or `dpkg -S /etc/mysql/my.cnf`.  For apache2, its the apache2.2-common package which owns most of the config.

`apt-file` is a handy utility you can install to search for this kind of thing as well.  After `apt-file update`,  `apt-file search /etc/mysql` should help figure out what package you need to reinstall.

Also note that you don't necessarily have to purge a package to replace missing config, there is a dpkg options `--force-confmiss` to replace missing config and `--force-confnew` to replace existing config, so you could probably fox your mysql problem with `apt-get -o DPkg::options::=--force-confmiss install --reinstall mysql-common`

Comment: thanks, that helped. Didn't expect that i should reinstall some other package rather the one i asked apt to install